# Is there a way to change the size of the Google SaveToDrive button?

Tags: html, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google SaveToDrive button on my webpage as shown here: https://developers.google.com/drive/savetodrive

However, the g-savetodrive button always shows up in a fixed size that does not match the rest of my UI/layout.  Are there any parameters to it that we can change the size of the button?

I tried other possibilities that I saw in +1 and Google SignIn buttons also (like data-size, data-width, data-height), but none of them worked.

Comment: https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js

Comment: Is it not possible to override the default styles with your own? If you're rendering via the JavaScript api (in which case the code is probably putting the styles inline), you could still use `!important` in your own style rules.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: not easily.

The google api embeds the icon in an iframe, which means you'd have to do some fiddling with jquery to apply any style rules to the button.

see: [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

To make matters worse the img source is very small. Stretching it yields a very fuzzy image that I wouldn't recommend. At the very least you'll want to find a large drive image and use that instead.

I think your best bet is creating a custom button that emulates googles class and id tags. Hopefully you can reverse engineer the button click and hook your custom button up to the same functionality.